# How to create tar in specified directory

Tags: java, tar

I am in directory /home

how I can create tar with files in /home/user/a/b/old/*. This tar should be in folder: /home/user/a/b/old/ and tar should contain files just files and folder in folder /home/user/a/b/old/* not the full path of this files . And I cant use command cd. Is this possible ?

This has to be run from Java, which is why it has a `[java]` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
(
cd /home/user/a/b/old/
tar cvf /tmp/old.tar .
mv /tmp/old.tar .
)
```

You might want to compress the archive as well with

```
(
cd /home/user/a/b/old/
tar cjvf /tmp/old.tar.bz2 .
mv /tmp/old.tar.bz2 .
)
```

Comment: Why cant you change directories?

Comment: You can use `cd` in Windows, Mac OS and UNIX. Which OS are you using? VMS?

Comment: because I executing this command from java code.

Comment: So you mean you need to use a shell like `bash -c` or `cmd /C` to cd but these are not on your system?

Comment: With ProcessBuilder, you can also set the working directory before you start the program. The move you can do in Java with File.rename().

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","tar cjvf /home/user/a/b/old/ /home/user/a/b/old/"});`

Comment: nope this doesnt work because in tar I have files with their path what I dont want